# Mongo Timeout Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been searching for hours, and I can't find out why this isn't working, could you give me a hand guys? I'm trying to implement mongodb on my project, it seems to connect all right, but when I try to modify/access something on it, it gives me this "Mongo Timeout Exception".

---

```
    try {
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(USER, DATABASE, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(HOST), Arrays.asList(credential));
        DB database = mongoClient.getDB(DATABASE);
        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(COLLECTION);
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        cursor.next();
        System.out.println("Success!");
    } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

---

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=104.236.68.242:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:394)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:571)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:368)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:622)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._next(DBCursor.java:551)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:701)
    at net.Heiden.DB.Testing.main(Testing.java:29)
```

Any Help is apreciated.
Thanks ^^

Comment: Chances are it never connected alright, it only attempted to connect when you invoke cursor.next(), since it's likely to be lazily initialized.

Comment: After some more tries, it said it was not able to send the socket, which values should I put as credentials? mongo is not clear enough. What is a pid?

Comment: Can you connect using the default Mongo client from the same machine?

Comment: Actually it's a host and I don't own it, but a teamate could connect with localhost.

Comment: Looks like its either an auth issue or its unreachable.  Could you connect from your machine via the commandline and  `mongo`?

Comment: Actually, the problem wasn't with mongo but with ubuntu login, I did it on windows and it worked (how to auth on ubuntu?)
I figured out a new issue, mongo isn't saving values as spected.
Let's suppose I have 3 values, saving value 1 with key "Name" , value 2 with key "Surname" and value 3 with key "Id".
- all the Names will be saved as a list.
- the first surname and id will be saved. then, when creating them mongo will believe they already exists and do nothing.

*There aren't too much mongo java tutorials on internet*